# How can I automatically assign categories for my custom posts in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I want to do this so I can simply use the category as a link in my menu to see all posts of that category.

I have found [this](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/set-category-to-a-custom-post-type-automatically) forum thread on this subject but I don't understand it.

It has the following solution:

```
function add_category_automatically($post_ID) {
    global $wpdb;
    if(!wp_is_post_revision($post_ID)) {
    $category = array (4);
    wp_set_object_terms( $post_ID, $category, 'category');
    }
}
add_action('publish_houses', 'add_category_automatically');
```

But I'm not sure what to put in the add_action function instead of publish_houses and what should go in $post_id.  I had hope to assign it in my functions.php file where I create my custom post type.

Ok, I have changed my code to:

```
function add_category_automatically($post_ID) {
global $wpdb;
if(!wp_is_post_revision($post_ID) && get_post_type($post_ID) == "offered") {
    $category = array (7);
    wp_set_object_terms( $post_ID, $category, 'category');
    }
}
add_action('publish_post', 'add_category_automatically');
```

Updated function:

```
global $wpdb;
if(!wp_is_post_revision($post_ID)) {
    $category = array (7);
    wp_set_object_terms( $post_ID, $category, 'category');
}
}
add_action('publish_offered', 'add_category_automatically');
```

Comment: This answer is outdated now. http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/publish_post

Answer (score 0):

**(Replaced my previous answer with a better one.)**

If your custom post type is called `offered` you could just replace `publish_houses` with `publish_offered` and put the original `publish_category_automatically` function, and the `add_action` line, in your functions.php file.

Comment: thanks, where is this function supposed to be?  I've got it in my custom functions file, so I'm not sure that it will get a $post_ID variable to it

Comment: Put both the `add_category_automatically()` function and the `add_action` line in your theme's functions.php file. The `add_action` line tells WordPress, "Call the `add_category_automatically` function every time a post is published, and pass that post to the function."

Comment: thanks but it's not working.  I'm adding new posts now and they aren't showing up under that category

Comment: Just replaced my answer with a better one ... try that.

Comment: In the function, replace the `wp_set_object_terms` line with:

    `wp_set_object_terms( $post_ID, 'the-slug-of-your-category', 'category');`

Comment: my category doesn't have a slug